# Notepad++ Dynamic Replace

Tags: notepad++

I need to replace this line:

```
tvec.at(21).interrupt();
```

with this line:

```
if (thr_ev_21.get()) thr_ev_21->interrupt();
```

I have lots of these lines at different numbers (i.e. 22, 23, 24, etc.)

Is there a way in Notepad++ (v7.5.3) to replace dynamically like so:

```
tvec.at(X).interrupt();
```

-->

```
if (thr_ev_X.get()) thr_ev_X->interrupt();
```

Comment: Note: you can create a string capture group like this: (`[^\s]+`) with `\1` or `\2` if it's your second group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the search mode to "Regular expression", and replace:

```
tvec.at\((\d+)\).interrupt\(\);
```

with:

```
if \(thr_ev_\1.get\(\)\) thr_ev_\1->interrupt\(\);
```

Notes:

- All of the actual parentheses in your search/replace strings have to be escaped with backslashes, since they have a special meaning in regular expressions.  You'd need to do the same with `[]{}?*` and probably a few other characters I'm forgetting.
- The match of an arbitrary number in the search string (`\d+`) is placed in parentheses, so it forms a capture group.  Since it's the first such group, you can refer to it as `\1` in the replacement string.  (And there's no problem with referring to it multiple times in the replacement.)

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `tvec\.at\((\d+)\).interrupt\(\);`
- Replace with: `if \(thr_ev_$1.get\(\)\) thr_ev_$1->interrupt\(\);`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
tvec\.at\(          : literally, dot and parenthesis have to be escaped
(\d+)               : group 1, 1 or more digits
\).interrupt\(\)    : literally, dot and parenthesis have to be escaped
```

Note:

Using Notepad++, parenthesis have to be escaped in the replacement part.